# How can i get the hour between two datetime in sql?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, select, hour

Below sql showing 57 hours, But,it's 44 hrs. How can i solve.

```
SELECT  DATEDIFF(Hour,'2018-11-20 2:26:38.000','2018-11-22 11:00:29.367')
```

Answer (score 2):

Use 24 hr format in both dates

```
SELECT  DATEDIFF(Hour,'2018-11-20 14:26:38.000','2018-11-22 11:00:29.367')
```

Comment: How can i convert  Datetime into 24 hrs format '2018-11-20 2:26:38.000'

Comment: you have include AM or PM to covert it into 24 Hr format 

SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, '2018-11-20 2:00:00 PM', 0)

Comment: @ShahanaAkterPingkey if you've not stored whether the time is AM or PM, then then you've already lost that information. If I said the time is 11:01 and asked you what time that was in 24 hour format, without additional information, how do you know it it's 11:01 or 23:01? (Answer: **you don't**). SQL Server can't infer this information either.

Comment: Ist date i am storing it can be AM/PM . But , last date i compared with the GETDATE()

Comment: @ShahanaAkterPingkey so, how do you tell if it's AM/PM?

Answer (score 0):

Not prefixing the hours to be two digits looks like it could be the issue, making it unambiguously in the afternoon gives your result.

```
/*------------------------
SELECT  DATEDIFF(Hour,'2018-11-20 14:26:38.000','2018-11-22 11:00:29.367')
------------------------*/

45
```

You're default Date Time format is probably 12 hour, and "2:…" is being treated as pm.

Using two digits for the hour should help.

```
/*------------------------
SELECT  DATEDIFF(Hour,'2018-11-20 02:26:38.000','2018-11-22 11:00:29.367')
------------------------*/

57
```

(SQL Server has a lot of backward compatibility which may be triggered is the input is not precisely formatted, ISO Date/Time formats always use two digits for hours, minutes, and seconds.)

If you are using a client (rather than fixed code in a Stored Proc/Function/Trigger/…) parameterising your queries avoids this issue: pass data as Date-Time type directly without any need to convert into a string.